# R Shiny DataTable filter cut off

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Here is the link to the data file, you may convert it in txt format.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1agR2wu82vBBv99DbmdXAQwyS9PF6nUUaKA1bGPH6eno/edit?usp=sharing

[Here is the screenshot for the cutoff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWzng.png)
When I add filter to the datatable in shiny dashboard, the dropdown box for the filter are cut off. Is there a way to fix this?( For example, for the 'Species' column, the filter dropdown box doesn't show the whole look of the two options, I need to widen the dropdown box in some way.) Here is the code which can be reproduced in Rstudio:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)


sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
 sidebarMenu(
  menuItem("Summary", tabName = "summary"),
  menuItem("Analysis", tabName = "analysis")
 )
)


body <- dashboardBody(
   tabItems(
     tabItem(tabName = "summary",
     fluidRow(
     #column(width = 4,
     box(
      title = "Studies", width = 12, status = "danger", solidHeader = TRUE,

      div(style = 'overflow-y: scroll; max-height: 600px', DT::dataTableOutput('table'))
      #div(style = 'overflow-y: scroll; max-height: 300px', tableOutput('table'))
    )
    #)
  ),
  hr(),

  fluidRow(
    box(
      title = "Type of cancer", status = "warning", width = 6, plotOutput("hist1")
    ),

    box(
      title = "Data type", status = "warning", color="yellow", width = 6, plotOutput("DataType"))
  )
),
tabItem(tabName = "analysis", h2("Analysis and plots"))
)
)




ui <- dashboardPage(
   dashboardHeader(title = "Cancer research updates", titleWidth = 300),
   sidebar,
   body
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   #test.table <- data.frame(lapply(1:3, function(x) {1:20}))
   #names(test.table) <- paste0('This_is_a_very_long_name_', 1:3)
   pcdata <- read.csv("./data/ProstateCancerInput_Final.txt", sep = "\t", encoding = 'UTF-8')
   colnames(pcdata)[1] <- ''
   colnames(pcdata)[6] <- 'Data type'
   colnames(pcdata)[9] <- 'Type of cancer'
   pcdata$Link <- paste0("<a href ='",pcdata$Link,"'>","Link to data","</a>")
   output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
   #test.table
   datatable(pcdata, rownames = FALSE, escape = FALSE,filter = 'top')
   })

   #windowsFonts(Arial=windowsFont("TT Arial")) 
 }

 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Can you make your question reproducible? Ideally, we should be able to copy the code right into our R session to reproduce the problem. That will make it much more likely that you'll get an answer – as it stands, I'm not sure exactly what the problem is and it would take a lot of work to reproduce it in order to test and solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for replying to my question! I have added the code needed to reproduce the bug. You can copy it into R and find out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Congrats on your first SO question :) I agree with @divibisan that a reproducible example (or even a screenshot) would help. If you're not sure how to make one, check out eg. this [article](https://www.jessemaegan.com/post/so-you-ve-been-asked-to-make-a-reprex/) or this [video](https://community.rstudio.com/t/video-reproducible-examples-and-the-reprex-package/14732).

From your description, I think you'd have add "overflow: visible" to the style of the div your table is in. [Here](https://t1.daumcdn.net/cfile/tistory/2279FB43533CEF4226) are some images of the different overflow property values and you can play around with them [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp). Feel free to ask more questions if you're not sure what I mean.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for replying to my question! I have added the code needed to reproduce the bug. You can copy it into R and find out. Thank you!